# SQLAlchemy - full load instance before detach

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

is there a way how to fully load some SQLAlchemy ORM mapped instance (together with its related objects) before detaching it from the Session? I want to send it via pipe into another processs and I don't want to merge it into session in this new process.

Thank you
Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll want to use the [`options()` method on the Query, with `eagerload()` or `eagerload_all()`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/orm/query.html?highlight=eagerload#query-options).

Here's an example of use from one of our apps, where the class `Controlled` has a relation called `changes` which brings in a bunch of `DocumentChange` records, which themselves have a relation `dco` that brings in one `Dco` object per instance.  This is a two-level eager-load, thus the use of the `eagerload_all()`.  We're using the `declarative` extension (in case that matters) and m.Session is a "scoped" (thread-local) session.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import eagerload, eagerload_all
...
controlled_docs = (m.Session.query(m.Controlled)
    .options(eagerload_all('changes.dco'))
    .order_by('number')
    .all())
```

If that's not sufficient, perhaps include a snippet or text showing how the relevant ORM classes are related and I could update the answer to show how those options would be used in your case.